# Changing a RelativeLayout's Visibility To GONE Making The Parent LinearLayout Completely Invisible

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Well... This is a weird problem I'm facing.

So one of my layout has one `LinearLayout` with two children `CardView` and `RelativeLayout` inside it. I'm trying to include that layout in another layout. And during a specific condition I'm trying to make the RelativeLayout's visibility GONE and make the CardView visibile programmatically.

But when I try to make the RelativeLayout invisible it makes the whole LinearLayout invisible in another layout while using `include`.

This is kinda weird to explain. So I have added a little video sample.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJyRC7mMX80

Code for Including that layout in another layout,

```
 <include
        android:id="@+id/add_image_btn"
        layout="@layout/edit_image_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"

        />
```

Code for the child layout,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:visibility="visible">


    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/edit_image_card_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:visibility="visible">


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,3:4"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:color/darker_gray">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/avatar2" />

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/edit_image_container"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/edit_image"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/baseline_edit_white_36dp"

                            />
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/add_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/md_grey_800"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:4"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@android:color/darker_gray">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/add_btn"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_a_photo_white_36dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure what's the problem is. So need some help :(

Comment: this layout seems like a bit of a mess, why do you have linear, relative and constraint all in one ?

Comment: Honestly I dont use constraint that much. But needed to use it in this layout to give  a specific aspect ratio to some of my images. And I use LinearLayout when I like to align the children vertically/horizontally. But most of the time I just use RelativeLayout just for its simplicity. But... I'm still experimenting with different kind of UI for this layout. So I was thinking about polishing everything in the end.  Anyways I don't think what's inside RelativeLayout & CardView can be the reason for this problem I'm facing... right? @a_local_nobody

Comment: not really sure, but if you were to simplify this layout using just a constraint layout, you might resolve your issue